# xml to plain text using xsl without hardcoding

Tags: xml, xslt

I've transformed an XML to plain text using xsl, I want to output the text of the nodes and attributes of it. I want the xsl to be generic, without containing the name of the node. I managed to do this. But when I have an empty node in xml it will be written in the output. I don't want that. How can I stop writting an empty node or attribute using xsl? I am looking for an implementation where it does not check for the name of a node but for all the nodes.

I have the following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<run xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <tests>
        <test name="a" attr1="" attr2="" attr3="an_value">
            <usecase name="name1">
                <description>Some description</description>
            </usecase>
            <usecase name="name2">
                <description>Descripton1</description>
            </usecase>
            <usecase name="name3">
                <description>Descripton2</description>
            </usecase>
        </test>
    </tests>
    <vip>
        <file name="b">
            <stat wins="1"/>
            <justifications/>
        </file>
        <file name="c">
            <stat wins="2" />
            <justifications/>
        </file>
    </vip>
</run>
```

I have the following XSL.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>


  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()"> 
<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/> 
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
        <xsl:call-template name="attributes"/> 
  <xsl:text>
  </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=" node()"/>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template name="attributes">
  <xsl:for-each select="@*">
<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/> 
  <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>


  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
run 
  tests 
  test name : a attr1 :  attr2 :  attr3 : an_value 
  usecase name : name1 
  description Some description

  usecase name : name2 
  description Descripton1

  usecase name : name3 
  description Descripton2

  vip 
  file name : b 
  stat wins : 1 
  justifications 
  file name : c 
  stat wins : 2 
  justifications
```

what xsl command I can use to not display the node justifications and the attributes attr1 and attr2 if they are all empty without hardcoding the xsl?

Desired output

```
run 
  tests 
  test name : a attr3 : an_value 
  usecase name : name1 
  description Some description

  usecase name : name2 
  description Descripton1

  usecase name : name3 
  description Descripton2

  vip 
  file name : b 
  stat wins : 1 

  file name : c 
  stat wins : 2
```

EDIT:
I updated the xsl to this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:variable name="empty_string" select="''" />

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()"> 
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/> 
                  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
                    <xsl:call-template name="attributes"/> 
                  <xsl:text>
                  </xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=" node()"/>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template name="attributes">
  <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.) != $empty_string">
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/> 
              <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
       </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am still looking on a condition to not write a node if it has no attributes and no childs. In that wasy the justification node will not be displayed.

Comment: What should be the result of `<test attr1="" attr2="attr value" attr3="">text value</test>`?

Comment: something like:
test attr2 : attr value

Comment: Why should `"text value"` be excluded?

Comment: my bad. Nothing should be excluded, the exclusion should only be use when the attribute is empty of value and a node has no childs or attribute, in the rest of the cases we extract all the data.

Comment: test  attr2: attr value text value
something like this.

Comment: "*not write a node if it has no attributes and no childs*" Why does your example not have such node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way you could do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:if test="text() or node() or @*">
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:if test=".!=''">
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
      <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzknt1/1

Comment: I tried your solution, you lose the description and the empty justification node is still present.

Comment: @BlajBogdan I updated my answer, it should now match what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The example is somewhat ambiguous, and the logic that needs to be applied here is not entirely clear. I am guessing you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*[@*|node()]"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/> 
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[string()]|text()"/> 
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/> 
    <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Personally, I wouldn't use space as a delimiter, because it can easily appear as part of a value (and so can a line feed, actually).

Comment: The example is just for testing. The idea is it can be an xml with any schema and only the data inside the nodes and attributes to be copied to plain text. The space part was because initially it was worse.

Comment: With your solution no more empty attributes are written, it's a good improvement over what I had initialy.